# how can i write unittest for my argparser?

Tags: unit-testing, pytest, robotframework, argparse, doctest

This is my argparse command line interface which use to options --filter and --count.

i'm (filtering/count) a data.json file, which i convert to list python.

My question is how do I write tests for that section of the code base?
by using unittest or other libraries(modules) python of tests

```py
def main(args):
    my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This program has to filter a list of elements containing a pattern and counts of People and Animals by counting the number of children ')
    my_parser.add_argument('--filter',
                        metavar='Filter',
                        type=str,
                        help='filter a list of elements containing a pattern')
    my_parser.add_argument('--count',
                        action='store_true',
                        help='the counts of People and Animals by counting the number of children')
    args = my_parser.parse_args()
    Filter= args.filter
    count = args.count
    data_filtered =[]
    list_count = []
    
    #Path to the data.json
    path = /path/to/data.json file

    # Python program to read
    # json file and convert them to list python 
    with open(path) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        if Filter:
            data_filtered=[dico for dico in data for dict1 in dico['people'] for animal in dict1['animals'] if Filter in animal['name']]
            if len(data_filtered) != 0:
                return data_filtered
                
        elif count:
            for dico in data:
                children = 0
                for ele in dico['people']:
                    animals = len(ele['animals'])
                    children += 1 + animals
                    ele['name'] += f" [{animals}]"
                dico['name'] += f" [{children}]"
                list_count.append(dico)
            return list_count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

`I trayed to do this but it doesn't work for me, i want to make tests of non regression, sincerlly i have never write those kind of tests and i dont know clearly how to do it`

```py
import unittest
from collections import namedtuple
from command_line import main

class TestMycommand_line(unittest.TestCase):

    args=['--filter=ry','--count']

    def test_filter(self):
        args = TestMycommand_line.args[0]
        print(args)
        res = main(args)
      

    def test_count(self):
        args = TestMycommand_line.args[1]
        res = main(args)
       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: tests on argparse are hard to do.You have simulate the commandline arguments (unittest is using its own parser).  There previous SO about this.

Comment: Yes I know it’s hard, that’s why I ask for help, I searched the net to find a similar example but I found examples that don’t work

Comment: try `args = my_parser.parse_args(argv)`, where `argv` comes from `def main(argv):`

Comment: I tryed but i have got this error : test_commande_line.py: error: unrecognized arguments: - - f i l t e r = r y